# Amazon web service : Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match in _POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, md5

I am submit feed request for **_POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_** using XML File **in Microsoft C#.**

I have generated XML file from Class.

Then after I have opened it in Filestream which I am sending in FeedContent and also computed MD5 value which I am sending in ContentMD5.

I have also set ContetType as application/xml

But Still I am getting Error as **the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed**

I am posting My code here.

Please guide me where I am wrong?

```
        public SubmitFeedResponse SubmitFeed()
        {
            SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
            SubmitFeedResponse submitFeedResponse = new SubmitFeedResponse();
            FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\file.xml", FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(fs);
                request.ContentMD5 = GetMd5HashFromStream(data);
            }
            request.FeedContent = fs;
            request.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaType.XMLStream);
            request.FeedType = "_POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_";
            request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
            request.MarketplaceIdList.Id.Add(this.marketPlaceID);
            request.Merchant = this.sellerID;
            request.MWSAuthToken = this.mwsAuthToken;
            request.PurgeAndReplace = false;
            submitFeedResponse = client.SubmitFeed(request);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close(); // or fs.Dispose()
            }
            return submitFeedResponse;
        }

        public string GetMd5HashFromStream(byte[] bytes)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
               var hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
               return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the service in use require the MD5 to be base64 encode such as [AWS Put Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) is spec'd?

Comment: @MadMyche yes it require MD5

Comment: I know that, but are you sending it as native hexadecimal or are you encoding as base64?

Comment: @MadMyche I am encoding at base64. Sorry I forgot to mention that in my question. just edited it.